# How to make javascript continuously checking for updates?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, loops

I have a javascript where if a user votes for the 3 questions, it enables the submit button. so I use the following;

```
if (feedone && feedtwo && feedthree == true) {
    button.disabled = false;
    button.style.opacity = 1;
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

The thing is this is at the last line, so when it runs the java script file, feedone, two and three are already false so even if later they become true, it doesn't read again for changes. Is there a way I can solve this? I tried having a while loop around the if statement so it keeps reloading, but made the program just loading the whole time.

Comment: ON every selection of vote run this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for an interaction with any of the vote inputs and run a function that checks if the submit button should be enabled.